# Should Interact With URL Changing Text View Color To Blue and Clickable

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit

I have a table view of posts, all of which contain URLs in their text bodies, and whenever I interact with the initial URL through:

```
- (BOOL)textView:(UITextView *)textView shouldInteractWithURL:(NSURL*)URL inRange:(NSRange)characterRange
    {
        //present webview here
        return NO;
    }
```

After I dismiss the modal view controller displaying the web view, the entire text of the text view turns blue and becomes clickable like the URL. I swizzled the UITextView implementation of setTextColor:, but to no avail, as the text color doesn't seem to be the problem alone since all the text is becoming clickable (if anyone knows the method that is called to do that, that would greatly help as well since I could swizzle its implementation). I have no idea what could be happening, and since it's not an explicit method call on my end, it might be a UIKit bug, but I'd really like a third party point of view.

Comment: I'm not sure, but that sounds to me like the tableView row was selected (and needs to be de-selected when you return).

Comment: I tried to reload the table view and unselect the row as well, but neither option worked. It turns subsequent textviews on table view cells blue as well (but not all of them, which makes it even more bizarre).

Comment: is it possible to attach screens to see the problem? then we can be more helpful

Comment: I figured it out guys, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I finally figured it out after a couple days, the solution was simply to use `[myTextView setAttributedString: myAttributedString]` instead of `[myTextView setText: myString]`. I'm guessing the automatic conversion to the text being blue and clickable is a bug in the UIKit, because I can't imagine why that would be desired functionality. In any case I hope this helps others who encounter this problem.